# No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path '/ProjectName'

Tags: xcode, github

2 questions:

I created a project in xcode which has the following folders in it:

```
app_icon.png
app_icon@2x.png
FacebookSDK.framework
ProjectName
ProjectName.xcodeproj
```

I used git to create local repo and push it to a newly created github repo.

When I try to clone the repository using xcode I get the following error:
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path '/ProjectName'

What is the issue? Is it the fact that I have FacebookSDK.framework folder in it?

After two attempts it miraculously was able to clone the project.. However, now when I try to commit anything in xCode the button says "Commit 1085 files" even though it shows 2 files changed...

Answer (score 0):

u can run it :
git rm —cached /ProjectName